# GLM Model comparison and selection with different response distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, cross-validation, method-comparison

I am proposing for my thesis... Pls help.

I have Y=weight of Baby, X1=Age of Mother X2=Age of Baby and X3=Sex of baby.
I assume Y~Normal with Identity link.
Also
I assume Y~Binomial with logit link
Furthermore, the first assumption,the models are nested therefore a Model selection will be done.
While, in the second assumption, Y will be transformed from continuous to binary(high 1 & low 0).
Now, the question is, am I allowed to compare the models and choose the model that best fits the problem.
Pls guide me well.

Comment: Should I assume this page is less functional or what. Please this poor brain soul